# Any ideas on how can i stream m3u8 video in android

Tags: android, video, video-streaming, android-videoview, m3u8

I am working on Android TV app and have to stream some videos. I am facing problem in playing m3u8 videos in videoview. Videoview is not working fine in all the devices. So I tried [GoogleExo](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer) player and [Vitamio](https://github.com/yixia/VitamioBundle) - it seems like both does not suppport m3u8 videos.

Does anyone know how to play m3u8 videos on android?

Comment: Google Exo Player supports m3u8...please verify the url

Comment: It does: https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/search?q=m3u8&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93

Comment: Ok! seems like GoogleExo Player supports m3u8 format. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By m3u8 if you mean [HLS](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/HTTPStreamingArchitecture/HTTPStreamingArchitecture.html) videos, Google's [ExoPlayer](https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/supported-formats.html) supports that. Also if you don't want to use ExoPlayer, android mediaplayer api has [limited support for HLS stream from android 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36833636/does-android-mediaplayer-supports-hls-audio-streams).

I would suggest if you can spend some money on purchasing some thirdparty players, they'll give the best playabck experience and features. Refer the following players

1. [NexStreaming](https://nexplayersdk.com/android-player-sdk/)
2. [Akamai](https://www.akamai.com/us/en/products/media-delivery/adaptive-media-player.jsp)
3. [Brightcove](https://support.brightcove.com/overview-brightcove-player-sdk-android)
4. [JW Player](https://developer.jwplayer.com/android-sdk/) - Its built on top of exoplayer